# Effect of Buffer Size in File I/O in Unix

Tags: linux, io, buffer

I am trying to understand the inner workings of `Unix` based OSs. I was reading on buffered I/O, and how the buffer size affects the number of system calls made, which in turn affects the total time taken by say, a copy program. To start with, here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

long currentTimeMillis();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int bufsize = atoi(argv[3]);
    printf("copying with buffer size %d\n", bufsize);
    char buf[bufsize];
    //open the file
    int fd_from = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    if(-1 == fd_from) {
        printf("Error opening source file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //file to be copied to
    int fd_to = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(-1 == fd_to) {
        printf("Error opening destination file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //copy
    long startTime = currentTimeMillis();
    int bytes_read = 0;

    long totalTimeForRead = 0;
    long totalTimeForWrite = 0;

    while(1) {

        long readStartTime = currentTimeMillis();
        int bytes_read = read(fd_from,buf,bufsize);
        long readEndTime = currentTimeMillis();
        if(0 == bytes_read) {
            break;
        }
        if(-1 == bytes_read) {
            printf("Error occurred while reading source file\n");
            return -1;
        }

        totalTimeForRead += readEndTime - readStartTime;

        long writeStartTime = currentTimeMillis();
        int bytes_written = write(fd_to,buf,bufsize);
        long writeEndTime = currentTimeMillis();
        totalTimeForWrite += (writeEndTime - writeStartTime);

        if(-1 == bytes_written) {
            printf("Some error occurred while writing file\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    long endTime = currentTimeMillis();
    printf("Total time to copy%ld\n", endTime - startTime);
    printf("Total time to write%ld\n", totalTimeForWrite);
    printf("Total time to read%ld\n", totalTimeForRead);

}

long currentTimeMillis() {
  struct timeval time;
  gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
  return time.tv_sec * 1000 + time.tv_usec / 1000;
}
```

I am using a 16G MacBook Pro with 2.9GHz Intel i7 (if this information would be useful). The size of source file is 2.8G. I was a bit surprised to see that total time take by `read()` is much smaller than `write()`. Here're my findings with a buffer size of 16K:

```
./a.out largefile dest 16382
copying with buffer size 16382
Total time to copy5987
Total time to write5330
Total time to read638
```

From what I have read, `write()` returns immediately after transferring the data to the kernel buffer from the user buffer. So the time taken by it is this time + the time taken for the system call initiation. `read()` also reads from kernel buffer to user buffer, so the total time taken should be same (in both cases, there is no disk I/O).

Why is it then that there is such drastic difference in the results? I asked this question on SO but I guess it was the wrong place.

Comment: If there's no disk I/O with `read()`, how does your program read the file data into the buffer? Sure, with `write()` the OS can allow the program to proceed while the OS deals with the I/O, but in the case of `read()` the program is forced to wait because it cannot proceed until the data has been read.

Comment: Your code seems to assume that you always read and write `bufsize` bytes in each call to `read()` and `write()`. This may not be the case. Also, _why_ are you surprised that writing is slower than reading? Data has to, at some point, be written to disk.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I guess due to the sequential read-ahead (at least with traditional disks). Even if it doing synchronous I/O with the disk, read should take more time right?

Comment: @Kusalananda data at some point has to be written into the disk. Yes, that's true. Quoting from Kerrisk's Linux Programming Interface, "However, we already saw that write() returns immediately after transferring data from user space to the kernel buffer cache. Since the RAM size on the test system (4 GB) far exceeds the size of the file being copied (100 MB), we can assume that by the time the program completes, the output file has not actually been written to disk.". My machine's RAM is 16G, so isn't this a possibility here?

Comment: I note that you accumulate write time before handling the error. Therefore it also contains error time.